# Properties of cubic graphs characterizable by the 2-factor structure

Tags: graph-theory

Petersen's Theorem states that every cubic, bridgeless graph contains a perfect matching and a disjoint 2-factor. I read in a paper that a cubic graph is 3-edge colorable if and only if it has a 2-factor with even cycles only.

> What other properties of cubic graphs is characterizable by the 2-factor structure?